# Loop through points on Chart without using .Activate

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through a bar graph and make any values above 2 red. The below code is currently working but I want to get around using .Activate

```
Sub Works()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets(1)

    With ws
        .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        For x = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
            If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).DataLabel.Caption > 2 Then
                'If above 2 make Red
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                'If below or equal to 2 make Blue
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

This was my proposed solution but I get a Run-time 438 error when I try to initiate the For loop. I'm assuming it's just a syntax error but I can't figure out how to do it without .Activate

```
Sub Fails()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets(1)

    With ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
        For x = 1 To .SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
            If .SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).DataLabel.Caption > 2 Then
                'If above 2 make Red
                .SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                'If below or equal to 2 make Blue
                .SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `With ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart`. Besides, Kudos for getting rid of `.Activate` (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your error already described to you by @A.S.H in the comments to your post.`Series` is a property of `ChartObject.Chart` and not `ChartObject`.

Try the code below, you could take advantage of VBA's chart capabilities with defining the following types of variables:

```
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim Ser As Series
Dim SerPoint As Point
```

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fails()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
    Dim Ser As Series
    Dim SerPoint As Point

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets(1)
    Set ChtObj = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1") '<-- set chart object

    With ChtObj
        Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
        For Each SerPoint In Ser.Points
            If SerPoint.DataLabel.Caption > 2 Then 'If above 2 make Red
                SerPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else 'If below or equal to 2 make Blue
                SerPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            End If
        Next SerPoint
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment by A.S.H., `.Chart` is the way to do it. However, you may also declare the chart as a chartObject and use the With myChart.chart in order to get the bonuses from the early binding.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fails()

    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim myChart     As ChartObject
    Dim x           As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set myChart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 2")

    With myChart.chart

        For x = 1 To .SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
            'I have changed a bit the line below, as far as I could not achieve what were you doing...---v
            If CLng(.SeriesCollection(1).Name) > 2 Then
                .SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                .SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            End If
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```